# Execute mysql query with variable from php webscript

Tags: php, mysql

I have to give rank to users based on scores stored in db table. For that I prepared query and working fine from MySql workbench. Here it is,

```
SET @rank=0;
        UPDATE pm_user pmu inner join 
            (SELECT user_id, (@rank := IF(@score <> total_score, @rank + 1, @rank)) rank, 
            (@score := total_score) total_score FROM pm_user ORDER BY total_score DESC) var 
            on var.user_id = pmu.user_id
        set 
            pmu.country_rank = var.rank
```

But now I have to execute this query from php webscript, for which I tried to execute it like this,

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    include("db_connection.php");

// Udate user ranks
    $query = mysql_query("SET @rank=0");
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE pm_user pmu inner join 
            (SELECT user_id, (@rank := IF(@score <> total_score, @rank + 1, @rank)) rank, 
            (@score := total_score) total_score FROM pm_user ORDER BY total_score DESC) var 
            on var.user_id = pmu.user_id
        set 
            pmu.country_rank = var.rank");

?>
```

But it didn't update anything in db table.
Am I going right. Or it should be executed differently?

Answer (score 0):

After many variations I solved it myself only by adding this line.

```
$query = mysql_query("SET @score=0");
```

So final code is,

```
$query = mysql_query("SET @rank=0");
$query = mysql_query("SET @score=0");

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE pm_user pmu inner join 
        (SELECT user_id, (@rank := IF(@score <> total_score, @rank + 1, @rank)) rank, 
        (@score := total_score) total_score FROM pm_user ORDER BY total_score DESC) var 
        on var.user_id = pmu.user_id
    set 
        pmu.country_rank = var.rank");
```

Actually it didn't required in MySql workbench but while executing from php, may be we require to initialize all variables I think.

Hope it may be helpful to someone facing same problem.